# Mostrar en el navegador resultados JSON de consulta SQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, json

ante todo, gracias acercarse. Es una consulta recurrente,pero no pude resolverlo buscando en otras consultas,que son más avanzados. El punto es que a partir del formulario y tras realizar la consulta obtengo, ya en la pagina de consulta.php en el navegador el print del resultado JSON, como se muestra
Quisiera poder ubicar esas variables en una tabla en el navegador.Agregar directamente en el codigo de la pagina de destino consulta.php.
Gracias por su ayuda.

index.php

```
     <form method="post" action="consulta.php">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Edad del Titular</label>
                <input id="edad1" name="edad1">
                <input id="edad2" name="edad2">
                <input id="hijos" name="hijos">
                <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                <button type="submit" name="btnconsulta">Consulta</button>
        </form>
```

consulta.php

```
 <?php
   header('Content-type:application/json; charset:utf-8');
   include_once "conexion.php";
   $objeto = new Conexion();
   $conexion= $objeto->Conectar();
   if (isset($_POST["telefono"],$_POST["email"]) and $_POST["telefono"] !="" and 
   $_POST["email"] !=""){
   $edad_1 = $_POST["edad1"];
   $edad2 = $_POST["edad2"];
   $hijos = $_POST["hijos"];
   $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
   $email = $_POST["email"];
 }

  $consulta = "SELECT plan_nombre,precio_total FROM precios WHERE edad_1 = $edad_1  AND  edad_2=$edad2 AND num_hijos =$hijos" ;
  $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
  $resultado -> execute();
  $data = $resultado->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  print json_encode($data)
?>
```

[{"plan_nombre":"INICIAL","precio_total":"7106"},{"plan_nombre":"INICIAL C/C","precio_total":"6142"},{"plan_nombre":"MEDIO","precio_total":"9638"},{"plan_nombre":"MEDIO C/C","precio_total":"8288"},{"plan_nombre":"PLUS","precio_total":"11498"},{"plan_nombre":"PREMIUM","precio_total":"10034"},{"plan_nombre":"PREMIUM PLUS","precio_total":"10661"},{"plan_nombre":"EXCELENT","precio_total":"11719"},{"plan_nombre":"PLATINUM","precio_total":"17339"},{"plan_nombre":"6000","precio_total":"22242"},{"plan_nombre":"TEST","precio_total":"4596"},{"plan_nombre":"BASICO","precio_total":"5871"}]

Answer (score 1):

Intento responderte de la forma mas sencilla que se puede solucionar lo que necesitas.

En el código que te pongo mas abajo viene todo comentado con las explicaciones. Aun así te dejo la explicación de lo que hay que hacer.

Una vez tienes el objeto JSON lo que tienes que hacer es decodificarlo para convertirlo en un array. Esto lo puedes hacer con la funcion json_decode() de php. Al convertirlo en un array, tendras un array de objetos **stdclass**.

Cada elemento del array que obtienes es, como digo en el párrafo anterior, un objeto **stdclass** y cada uno de estos objetos contiene el nombre del plan y el precio del mismo.

Lo siguiente que hacemos es recorrer cada uno de esos elementos del array y en cada uno de ellos lo convertimos de un objeto en un array asociativo para que sea mucho mas fácil trabajar con él.

Una vez hecho esto tendremos un array en el cual, cada uno de los elementos, tendremos un array asociativo con dos elementos: el nombre del plan y el precio.

Por lo tanto ya solo quedará en cada iteración del bucle imprimir esos datos en una celda de cada fila de una tabla.

Te adjunto el código comentado para que se entienda mejor: (haz scroll horizontal para verlo completo o copia y pega en un editor para verlo aún mejor)

```
<?php
//  Metemos el JSON en una variable
    $json = '[{"plan_nombre":"INICIAL","precio_total":"7106"},{"plan_nombre":"INICIAL C/C","precio_total":"6142"},{"plan_nombre":"MEDIO","precio_total":"9638"},{"plan_nombre":"MEDIO C/C","precio_total":"8288"},{"plan_nombre":"PLUS","precio_total":"11498"},{"plan_nombre":"PREMIUM","precio_total":"10034"},{"plan_nombre":"PREMIUM PLUS","precio_total":"10661"},{"plan_nombre":"EXCELENT","precio_total":"11719"},{"plan_nombre":"PLATINUM","precio_total":"17339"},{"plan_nombre":"6000","precio_total":"22242"},{"plan_nombre":"TEST","precio_total":"4596"},{"plan_nombre":"BASICO","precio_total":"5871"}]';
    
//  Convertimos el Json en un array de objetos STDCLASS
    $datos = json_decode($json);
    
//  Ahora cada uno de los elementos que contiene la variable $datos en un objeto con el nombre y el precio de cada plan.
    
//  Escribimos el html de inicio de la tabla y las cabeceras de la tabla
    echo "
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Plan</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
        </tr>
    ";
    
//  Empezamos a recorrer el array de objetos
    foreach ($datos as $plan){
        
//      En cada variable $plan esta el objeto con el nombre y el precio. Por lo tanto loconvertimos de objeto a array asociativo. Para hacer esto convertimos el objeto en un Json con la funcion Json_encode($plan) y posteriormente lo convertimos de un Json a un array con la funcion Json_decode.
        $plan = json_decode(json_encode($plan),true);;
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($plan); echo "</pre>";
        
//      Ahora la variable $plan tiene un array asi: >Array([plan_nombre] => INICIAL,[precio_total] => 7106) que es mucho mas fácil de trabajar con él mas que con un objeto.
//      Pasamos el array a dos variable para usarlas dentro del echo

        
        $plan_nombre = $plan['plan_nombre'];
        $precio = $plan['precio_total'];
        
//      y escribimos las celdas con los valores que necesitamos
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td>$plan_nombre</td>
            <td>$precio</td>
        </tr>
        ";
    }
    
//  Por ultimo cerramos la etiqueta de tabla
    
    echo "</table>";

?>
```

Espero haberte ayudado :)

Comment: Hola, tu respuesta me llevó al resultado esperado. Lo modifiqué, agregué desde  foreach y como los datos de origen el que ya tenía ($data as $plan), omiti los siguientes dos renglones y a a partir de $plan_nombre = $plan['plan_nombre']; hasta el final.  Y quedó con el título

Comment: Genial! Si te ayudó, ¿Podrías votar mi respuesta como favorita? Muchas gracias! :)